# Plural or singular of 'case study'

Tags: grammatical-number

I have the following sentence and I need your help:

"This and the previous **case study** show the benefits of optimization approaches."

Is it correct to use the singular for 'case study' altough I am referring to two case study/studies?
I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: This, and all previous case *studies* (two or  more) have shown that...

Comment: Yep, should be plural in that context.

Comment: It depends. (This and the previous) case studies ... // This and (the previous case study) ....

Comment: This is unclear, as the comments indicate. Is the _total_ number of case studies 2, or more?

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. The total number of case studies is 3. But only on 2 the benefits are shown.

Comment: Then it should be "This, and _a/one_ previous case study show..."

Comment: Much simpler would be _This case study and the previous one show .._

Comment: Two out of (the) three case studies show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*This and the previous case study show the benefits of optimization approaches*" means there are two case studies that have shown the benefits, "this" case study, and some other one. It isn't clear from the sentence whether there are any other case studies.

It is correct to use the singular because in that sentence "the previous case study" is one case study. From the structure, we understand that the sentence means, "This case study and the previous case study..."